# Как вывести дату в заданном формате?

Tags: php

Как вывести дату в таком формате `2015-05-20T14:22:17+00:00`?

Comment: а чем [date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) не устраивает? Там даже пример есть подходящий (`echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));`)

Comment: DATE_ATOM подходит, из Mysql тоже преобразует?

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться предопределенным классом `DateTime` и его методом `format()`. Для нужного вам формата определены константы `DateTime::ATOM` и `DateTime::W3C` (они эквивалентны)

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format(DateTime::W3C); // 2016-07-30T23:34:11+03:00
```

Если формат, заданный константой по каким-то причинам не подходит, можно задать формат даты самостоятельно

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');
```